# reactjs serve xml file from root path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, webpack-dev-server

I want to show the sitemap.xml file from the root path but i get the following error.

Cannot GET /sitemap.xml

This is the url i am trying to access: http://localhost:8080/sitemap.xml

i added the file to the public directory.

this is my webpack configuration:

devServer: removeEmpty({
      hot: ifDevelopment(true),
      publicPath: "/",
      historyApiFallback: true,
    }),

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy `sitemap.xml` file to the build directory
you can use [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) for that